# Proper way to get string list in JNI

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a JNI function in C which is getting passed in a Java FILE class which represents a directory listing. I would like to call the list() function and get the list of strings (files in the directory). What is the best way to do this?

Right now I have

```
static void* my_function(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject dir){
    jarray listRet;
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, dir);
    jmethodID method = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "list", "()[Ljava/lang/String");
    listRet = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, cls, method);

    jsize stringCount = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, listRet);
}
```

However, by adding logging statements, it seems that it never gets past the GetObjectClass call.
So, is this call correct? Further, is the GetMethodID call correct? The return type of list() is a (java) String[].
Is there anywhere else that I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is not a static method of `File`. That is, it belongs to an instance of `File` (`dir` in your case), not to the `File` class.

So instead of:

```
listRet = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, cls, method);
```

you should be using:

```
listRet = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, dir, method);
```

---

Also, you seem to be missing a semicolon in the signature for `list`. It should be `"()[Ljava/lang/String;"`

Comment: Thanks for the insight! However it still seems to be choking. CallObjectMethod takes a class as its second parameter. Is it ok to pass in the jobject dir directly like this?

Comment: Nope, `CallObjectMethod` takes a `jobject` as its second parameter. Perhaps you're thinking of `CallStaticObjectMethod` (which isn't applicable here).

Comment: Whoops! Of course, you are correct :) I was looking at GetMethodID(). I've tried casting the dir as a class here, too, and no dice. It seems to keep failing on the GetMethodID.

Comment: For `GetMethodID` you should be passing `cls`, not `dir`. Have you verified that `cls` is non-NULL?

Comment: Hmm. Looks like I was wrong, the GetObjectClass is never coming back. I stuck a log message before and after it. The one before it shows up, the one after never comes.

Comment: Actually, looks like there was something earlier in the C code that was causing problems. Testing this as a stand alone JNI application worked just fine. Thanks again for your help!